# How did the transformation of the first sphere affect the second sphere without using glPushMatrix?

Tags: opengl, glut, transformation

When I was running this code I got 2 spheres that are scaled and the transformation of the first sphere also affected the second sphere.

```
 glTranslatef(0,1,0);
 glScalef(1,1,0.5);
 glutWireSphere(0.5, 20, 16);  

 glTranslatef(0,-1,0);
 glutWireSphere(0.5, 20, 16);
```

I have 3 questions:

1. `glTranslate` and `glScale` considered to be one or two matrices when I use the pop/push matrix?
2. how did the transformation of the first sphere affect the second sphere?
3. how can I save only the scaling transformation with the `glPushMatrix` so that the   `glTranslatef(0,1,0)` won't affect the second sphere ?

Comment: The simplest answer, by far, is: *"draw the second sphere first"* (before the Translate and Scale calls). Then you don't have to do this unnecessary `glTranslatef(0,-1,0);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should know that you're using deprecated functionality. You should look up how to do the above with shaders.

That said, to answer your questions:

1. There is a current transform matrix. Any matrix operations you perform are concatenated onto the current transform matrix (except `glLoadMatrix()` which overwrites it). So scales, translates, multiplies, etc. all change the current matrix. When you draw some geometry using `glBegin()` and `glEnd()`, they use the current transform matrix. (Much of OpenGL works this way. There's a bunch of state and whatever the current state is, that's what's used to draw stuff.)
2. Since the transformations are concatenated, the first is drawn with just the translate and scale. The second is drawn with the translate and scale plus another translate. The second translate happens after a scale, so it's units are different than the first translate's units.
3. I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve with pushing and popping the matrices. Normally, you'd use `glPushMatrix()`/`glPopMatrix()` like this:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0,1,0);
glScalef(1,1,0.5);
glutWireSphere(0.5, 20, 16);  
glPopMatrix();

glutWireSphere(0.5, 20, 16);
```

But did you want both to be scaled, but only 1 to be translated instead? If you clarify, I can fix the above to do what you intend.

Basically, `glPushMatrix()` saves the current state of the matrix. You then make any changes to it that you want to, and draw any geometry with those changes. Then when you call `glPopMatrix()` it restores it to the state it was in when you called `glPushMatrix()`.

Comment: I was confused because I was told that whenever I push a new matrix to the stack the previous one (in the head of the stack) is deleted.. but in this code the previous matrix (which was : glTranslatef(0,1,0);
glScalef(1,1,0.5);) was still in the stack after applying the glTranslatef(0,-1,0);... or maybe I didn't understand it correctly..

Comment: why did u say that the transformations are concatenated?

Comment: The previous matrix is not deleted when you push a new one onto the stack. The purpose of a stack is to save the old data so you can restore it later. If you look at [the docs for `glPushMatrix`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml), it says, "glPushMatrix pushes the current matrix stack down by one, duplicating the current matrix. That is, after a glPushMatrix call, the matrix on top of the stack is identical to the one below it."

Comment: Every time you make a call to `glTranslate()`, `glRotate()`, `glScale()`, etc., that function happens in addition to the current transformation matrix. If you start with `glLoadIdentity()`, you have an identity matrix (no scaling, translation, rotation, etc.). If you call `glTranslate()`, then the world is translated. If you then call `glScale()`, the the translated world you already have is scaled. It doesn't get rid of the translation. The scale is concatenated onto the translation.

Comment: I meant without using the glPushMatrix.. when I do any new transformation on a new object the matrix in the head of the stack (from previous transformation of a different object) is changing to the matrix of my new transformation..no ?

Comment: The only way I know of to replace the current transformation rather than add on to it, is to use either `glLoadIdentity()` or `glLoadMatrix()`. All the other matrix functions multiply the current matrix by a new matrix containing the transformation you requested (such as a translation or scale or whatever). So no, it's not changing to the matrix of your new transformation. It's adding your transformation on to the current one.

Comment: thank you very much.. only now I got what u meant.. that I use the pushMatrix to restore a state.. and the popMatrix to go back to that state...